# index out of range?

Tags: python3, signal

```py
# load parameters file

yml = yaml.load(open(sys.argv[1]))
# imports 

for pkg, functions in yml['imports'].iteritems():   
    stri = 'from ' + pkg + ' import ' + ','.join(functions)
    exec(stri)
```

for the above code i get an error

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

in line 2..can anyone help me out ?

Comment: In the code listed the error should show on line 3 not on the empty line 2. Am I right? The code is also missing `import sys` and `import yaml` before the first command.

Comment: `interitems()` is for Python2, you have a Python3 tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line:

```py
yml = yaml.load(open(sys.argv[1]))
```

...assumes you pass the value, to be used in the line, as an argument when you call the script:

```
<script> <argument>
```

but probably you just ran the script without any argument.

Arguments are *listed*, where the command to call the script is the first item in the list (the first item is *index* 0).

```py
[<script>, <sys.argv[1]>, <sys.argv[2]>]
```

Since you run the script with only its command (`sys.argv[0]`), `sys.argv[1]` is referring to a (list-) item that does not exist, raising an `IndexError`.